# slf4j log method parameters - a generic way?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

I would like to be able to do this kind of magic:

```
logger.info("Entering function foo", param1, param2 .... param N);
```

I want to log (info) all my entries to methods, so the following way is not very friendly (i will have to spend to much time counting the {} to see if its the exact number etc..):

```
logger.error("Entering function foo, {} {} {} ... {}", param1, param2 .... param N);
```

I mean is'isn't there a better way (no aspects solutions please).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to write a small utility:

```
logger.error("Entering function foo, " + params(N), param1, param2 .... param N);

static String params(int length) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sb.append("{} ");
  }
}
```

This is ugly but I could not think of a better way using pure SLF4J. A specific implementation might offer a better solution. Alternatively do the following:

```
logger.error("Entering function foo, {}", Arrays.asList(param1, param2 .... param N));
```

if this format change is tolerable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclipse? [eclipse-log-param plugin](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-log-param/) can help you.

If you have one template like the next under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates:

[image: Template in eclipse]

```
if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
    LOG.info("${cursor}: ${formatted_logback_method_parameters});
}
```

You can automatically generate the log statement, using the parameters of the current method. An array of objects is created if necessary.

[image: Using the template]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this approach is going to cost you least overhead if in most case you are turning off such logging:

psuedo code:

```
class LogParams {
    private Object[] params;
    public LogParams(Object... params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (params == null || params.length == 0) {
             return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object p : params) {
            sb.append(p).append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

and in your code, you simply do

```
logger.info("Entering function, params: {}", new LogParams(p1, p2, p3, p4..., pn));
```

(You can make a factory method for LogParams so it looks even shorter).

This approach will delay any string construction until it really needs to do logging.  Maybe helpful in some case.